# Radeon HD 4670 driver for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, amd-radeon

I have a computer with Windows 10 Home and my video card is Radeon HD 4670.

It worked very well but now I had to reinstall Windows and I have no internet. The screen resolución is stuck at 1280 x 1024

How can I convince Windows to change the screen resolution to 1920 x 1080 ?

I tried the generic driver from AMD and it doesn't work.

Comment: AMD notes on their support page that this won't work (and why) https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-615

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There never were any drivers for that card in Win10. It was legacied before Win10 was announced.

Best you might do is the appropriate Win 8 diver from https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/ati-radeon-hd-4000-series/ati-radeon-hd-4670

If you can't get it directly on the computer concerned, there's always 'sneakernet' on a USB stick.

Comment: The Windows 8 driver worked perfectly, thanks!